# Difference between .getAttribute and dataset in JS

Tags: javascript, dataset, getattribute

I have been using .getAttribute and today found out about .dataset, so i was wondering what the differences are and when should each be used.

So here is an example. Let's say we have a paragraph:

```
<p class="test" data-something="this is a test">some text</p>
```

if we use .getAttribute

```
let testText = document.querySelector('.test');
let testGetAttribute = testText.getAttribute('data-something');
console.log(testGetAttribute);
```

we get as output "this is a test".

if we use .dataset

```
let testText = document.querySelector('.test');
let testDataset = testText.dataset.something;
console.log(testDataset);
```

we also get "this is a test".

So, is there a difference between this two approaches? Are there some benefits in using one over the other?

Thank you!

Comment: In HTML, you should only add attributes that are specified as belonging to the particular HTML element. If you create your own named attributes, you risk a name clash with a current or future attribute names. So *data-\** attributes were created so you can use it as a prefix for any attribute you wish to add. The rest you can get from [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). The use of *dataset* is just a convenient getter, rather than using `element.getAttribute(data-whatever)`.

Comment: `dataset` is more recent, works in current browsers and makes nicer code to read, but if you're handling large numbers of `data` attributes, it's slower that `getAttribute`, although that speed difference is negligible for smaller cases, where `dataset` is fine. See https://jsperf.com/getattribute-vs-dataset

Comment: `dataset` [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#browser_compatibility) is really good, so performance aside it will hardly crash anywhere

Answer (score 2):

I'm only replying this because I faced a difference between the two methods that actually affected the functioning of my application.

I did `getAttribute('data-id')` and `dataset.id` to collect a todo item `id`.

For getAttribute, if I ran through the debugger line by line, it worked fine. If I didn't, all sorts of wonky things would happen. For dataset.id it worked fine either way.

If you're curious about it, you can check lines 201 and 202 in my code: 
https://glitch.com/~wnc-reading-exercise-3 Comment out line 201 and uncomment line 201.

When running the app, try toggling complete on a todo item and see what happens to the DOM. If you go around toggling a few at a go you'll see some strange values show up.

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain the difference though?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get `data-something` in JS both work or when the "data-something" is added in JS with `dataset.something` and want to get it.

But performance getAttribute is much better than dataset ([test performance reference](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/14432/0/getattribute-vs-dataset))

getAttribute x 122,465 ops/sec ±4.62% (60 runs sampled)

dataset x 922 ops/sec ±0.58% (62 runs sampled)